# jQuery Dialog Button - Keep Applied Style

Tags: jquery, button, dialog, default

I have a jQuery dialog and wanted to set one of the buttons to look and act like a default button while still being able to keep focus on the form elements. I was able to successfully do this using the code below but the problem I am running into is when the default button is clicked (not when enter is hit), the style that I applied gets removed. I tried adding the style back on after the button was clicked but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```
open: function ()
{
    $('#FieldName').focus();
    $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').addClass('ui-state-focus');

    $(this).keydown(function (event)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
        }
    });
}
```

Update:
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98v6Q/2/

In order to see the problem while using the fiddle code, run the fiddle and then click anywhere in the dialog or the form. You'll notice the default state of the button remains. Click the 'Create Account' button then click anywhere inside or outside of the form and you'll notice the button state changes and it shouldn't.

Comment: It would help to see the relevant HTML and possibly a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem.

Comment: I updated my question and included a fiddle.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to have it always look focused? I do not see the Create Account button look any different after it is clicked and then loses focus. It still has the darker blue background color that the Cancel button gets if you hover over it.

Comment: @RubenInfante - In my update notes above, I stated you needed to click off the dialog on in the dialog to see the focus change. I was unable to include the jQuery validation code that I use in the fiddle. Once the validation happens, the dialog automatically switches focus to the first invalid field which causes the button to revert to an unfocused state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off applying your own css.

Instead of `.addClass('ui-state-focus');` you should add a class you declare in your css.

IE:

`.addClass('ui-button-primary');`

then in css

```
.ui-button-primary{
    //Your style here
}
```

Comment: I thought about that but I wanted to be able to switch jQuery themes and not have to code a new focus look for each additional theme.

Comment: Well bold it or something generic?

Comment: I actually tried plugging a new class into the fiddle I created and could not get any type of style to override the button. Not exactly sure why.

Comment: You should look at the styles being applied to your button in the debugger, then aim to alter them. Keep in mine CSS specificity, !important tags and inline CSS when making your changes. You should also check if jquery UI contains a primary button class

Comment: How easy one forgets the basics sometimes. Your solution worked, however, I really wish I could have used the jQuery UI defaults and not have to add my own styles. Thanks for the help.